# How to make sure SQLiteOpenHelper and SharedPreferences will get deleted on application uninstall

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences, sqliteopenhelper

I am working with SQLiteOpenHelper and SharedPreferences on my Android application,
when I unsinstall it and install again, I see that some data remain from last version,

**How can I make sure that when a user delete the app - all related data will be deleted also?**

Thank you

Comment: "when I unsinstall it and install again, I see that some data remain from last version" -- how *precisely* did you try to uninstall the app?

Comment: The same as any user will do... long hold the icon and drag it to "uninstall app"

Comment: Try it again, this time uninstalling it from Settings > Apps. Also, please explain how you determined that data remained from the previous installation.

Comment: I read shared preferences during my app and they are exist with old data

Comment: Fully uninstalling an app will remove the app's internal storage directories, including the default locations for databases and preferences. So, either you are not fully uninstalling the app, or your code is storing this data in non-traditional locations, or your device manufacturer really screwed something up.

Comment: I test it with regular uninstallation (as any regular user will do). I don't chose where to store the data somewhere special so I assume it uses the default place to store it